# Using :nth from a specific class in list

Tags: css, sass

What I would like to do is add a class to the center list item and then from there eventually add a different background colour to each item from there. At the moment I add a class `.is-middle` to the list and for now I want to add the `background:red` to each list item from there on, I'm using `&.is-middle:nth-of-type(1n)` but I'm not sure that's the correct thing to be doing?

**SCSS**

```
.ctn {

  li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightgrey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;

    &.is-middle:nth-of-type(1n) {
        background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

**Pen:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/mgfxJ

Comment: use this for testing, which is pretty quick: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/. also, why don't you use the `~` selector, after you just selected the middle one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will color evey `li` element which comes after the `.is-middle` classed element:

```
.ctn {
  li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightgrey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;

    &.is-middle ~ li{ background:red; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would never have though to use ~ great call! I must remember that!!

Comment: well if you liked it why did you vote up instead of marking it as accepted? :) it makes no sense

Comment: can you tell me why this doesn't work http://codepen.io/styler/pen/mgfxJ I'm trying to change some of the list item colours from .is-middle onwards?

Comment: This cannot work for the simple reason: you have chosen to colorize `nth-child(1)` for example. what you think is 1, is actually the very first `li` element, and not the first one **after** your middle one, since this is not how CSS works. `1` is an absolute value, not relative to any previous selector and does not have a "starting" point.

Comment: thanks vsync, i appreciate your answer! what way would you approach this? Maybe loop through the second half or list items and add a class to each and work on those?

Comment: do you have any reason why not color then with javascript? another solution would be to inject a `style` tag to the page and put there the correct formula, which is something like this - `nth-child(n + middle){...}` where middle is the index of the middle element, where only js could know.